# How to install kivy v1.9.1 or any specific version in ubuntu

Tags: python, kivy

**I tried these commands which is in installation guide as well but it install latest version**

**where i need kivy-1.9.1**

*In my case this command installs v1.7.2 of kivy:*

1. Add one of the PPAs as you prefer

stable builds:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
```

nightly builds:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy-daily
```

2. Update your package list using your package manager

`$ sudo apt-get update`

3. Install Kivy

Python2 - python-kivy 
  `apt-get install python-kivy`

Comment: execute: `sudo pip install kivy=1.9.1`

Comment: @eyllanesc ^^ `sudo pip install kivy==1.9.1`

from this i only get gz file

Comment: I recommend using virtualenv to not affect the packages of your OS:

Comment: But in my case i don't want to use virtualenv- I need direct installation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for particular kivy version

First remove existing kivy from your system.

```
sudo apt-get remove python-kivy
```

install dependencies for kivy

```
sudo apt-get install -y \
    python-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python \
    python-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev
```

then install kivy with a specific version

```
sudo pip install kivy==<version>
```